# Node JS : I need to format the date in this format (11:20:00:13/04/2016)

Tags: node.js

i have the date like this

```
112000130416(HHmmssddmmyy)
```

but i need it to format it into the following in Node JS

```
11:20:00:13/04/2016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use moment.js module to do that.

```
var moment = require('moment');

var date = moment((112000130416).toString(), 'HHmmssDDMMYY');
console.log(date.format('HH:mm:ss:DD/MM/YYYY'));
```